# How to setup Azure self hosted integration runtime for linux based db servers

Tags: linux, postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have postgresSQL server on my local linux Ubuntu machine. I want to connect it to Azure Data Factory using self hosted integration runtime. How to setup Azure self hosted integration runtime for Linux based Database servers.

I am able to do it for Windows, but not able to find any documentation for linux OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ishwar Sukheja, welcome to stack overflow. the document said it only suport windows operating system. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? Did you see my answer? If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know. If you want get more helps, please reply us, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, we can't install self-hosted integration runtime in Linux, it's not supported. Please ref the Azure [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-ir-compute-resource-and-scaling):

- Install Self-hosted IR on an on-premises machine or a virtual machine
  inside a private network. **Currently, we only support running the
  self-hosted IR on a Windows operating system**.

HTH.